# I want to print '$0.00', when there is a particular node missing in XML

Tags: javascript, reporting-services, report, birt

I want to print '$0.00', when 'wd:Report_Entry' node missing in XML for wd:Academic_Period = "...2020 Summer".

Below is the XML data for reference -

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<wd:Report_Data xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday.report/Financial_Aid_Award_Letter">
    <wd:Report_Entry>
        <wd:Academic_Period wd:Descriptor="2020 Summer (05/26/2020-08/12/2020)">
            <wd:ID wd:type="Academic_Period_ID">ACADEMIC_PERIOD_2020_Fall</wd:ID>
        </wd:Academic_Period>
        <wd:Total_Financial_Aid>170</wd:Total_Financial_Aid>
    </wd:Report_Entry>
    <wd:Report_Entry>
        <wd:Academic_Period wd:Descriptor="2020 Spring (01/21/2020-05/18/2020)">
            <wd:ID wd:type="Academic_Period_ID">ACADEMIC_PERIOD_2020_Spring</wd:ID>
        </wd:Academic_Period>
        <wd:Total_Financial_Aid>265</wd:Total_Financial_Aid>
    </wd:Report_Entry>
    <wd:Report_Entry>
        <wd:Academic_Period wd:Descriptor="2020 Summer (05/26/2020-08/12/2020)">
            <wd:ID wd:type="Academic_Period_ID">ACADEMIC_PERIOD_2020_Summer</wd:ID>
        </wd:Academic_Period>
        <wd:Total_Financial_Aid>170</wd:Total_Financial_Aid>
    </wd:Report_Entry>
</wd:Report_Data>
```

Comment: Any suggestion on this issue please!

Comment: Reframing this question: How can I detect to check if any particular xml node is missing or not?